# Change iFrame size using its own script

Tags: javascript, iframe

My question is simple, I have `iframe` with two buttons and some javascript code inside. When i click these buttons, i want to resize this `iframe` using its own script. I couldn't find any tutorial for this. However i don't use jQuery for this.

I tried few methods to get `iframe` object nothing works. Is there possible way to do this compatible with cross browsers? and is this a bad practice?

**Main html page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <style>
            iframe{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="pages/widget.html" height="150" width="150" id="iframe1">
    </body>
</html>
```

**iFrame**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="setSize1()">Maximize</button>
        <button onclick="setSize2()">Minimize</button>
        <script>
            function setSize1(){
                //get iframe object
                iframe.style.height="300px";
            }

            function setSize2(){
                //get iframe object
                iframe.style.height="150px";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you would need to reference the parent page and adjust it from there. The content in the iframe has no relationship to it.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t u just use JavaScript:

```
<script>const beer = {
name: 'Belgian Wit',
metric: 10,
keywords: ['pale', 'cloudy', 'spiced', 'crisp'] };



const markup = `<div class="beer"><h2>${beer.name}</h2><p class="brewery">${beer.metric +1}</p></div>`;  document.body.innerHTML = markup;</script>
```